# How to redirect these old urls to new ones (subfolder) via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

I am a newbie and would like to redirect all my old urls to new ones (moved as subfolder) via htaccess. Also, with 301 permanent redirect.

Old url pattern looks like:
http://www.mydomain.com/de/myoldpage.html
New url pattern should be:
http://www.mydomain.com/shop/de/myoldpage.html

I am using the same domain and same page urls but only my shop is moved to a subfolder "shop".
How can i write a redirect rule to redirect all the urls in this pattern.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(de/.*)$ /shop/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^de/(.*)$ shop/de/$1 [L,R]
```